# How to prevent from closing (dismiss) spinner in dropdown mode after item's selection

Tags: android

I want to make custom spinner in which user can select one of the items on dropdown list (like in normal spinner) but I want to prevent from closing (collapsing/dismiss) dropdown list after item selection. Or closing dropdown when user tap two times on item instead of single tap. Is anyone here knows how to achive such behavior using spinner?

Answer (score 0):

Set itemSelectedListener on your spinner and onItemSelected() run this code

```
spinner.setClickable(false);
```